# How to create menu in AsideSecond as in video but in version 1.10?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to follow the docs example here, Im using 1.10
http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Orchard-TV/#getting-started-with-taxonomies
Getting a taxonomy to show up as a menu on the "asidesecond" area.  I see no taxonomy widget show up when I go to setup the default layer.

Ive got my taxonomy defined with terms and a few blog posts with a taxonomy associated with it.  Did the taxonomy change regarding how to show it within a menu?

Comment: You need to clarify what you have so far so we can reproduce it. It might be the missing widget or wrong layer rules.